# ATCL programme notes : what do I need to include?

Tags: exam

It seems that there is a clear instruction about the programme notes for DipABRSM ([official guide](http://www.abrsm.org/resources/writingProgNotesApr05.pdf)).

According to the Trinity diploma syllabus,

> ...
>
> There should be a concise note on each piece, focusing on its context, content and significance. A useful guide to the kind of approach looked for may be taken from professional public concert programmes.
>
> Timings for each work or movement should be included. Your notes should avoid lengthy biographical detail and/or generalisations about composers and styles. Plagiarism should be avoided
>
> ...

What do I need to include, or must not include, in my ATCL programme notes? For example, DipABRSM does not allow appearance of candidate name in the programme notes.

Comment: i feel that the chances of someone with the ability to teach and understand Diplomas and the fact that the one in question is a diploma specific to the UK and commonwealth make sure that a person able to answer this unlikely to be found here. Have you tried the ABRSM forums as I recall they have a whole section geared to diploma candidates.

Comment: Your quote from the syllabus seems to answer your own question. Beyond that, Google is your friend. www.trinitycollege.com/resource/?id=4001 (found by Google!) says "A written programme, including programme notes, must be handed to the examiner at the start of the examination" so there is no need identify yourself in any other way. Google will also find plenty of general guidance and some examples to follow.

Comment: @NeilMeyer you may be right, so I'd just put the question here and wait if someone can answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because matriculation questions are beyond the scope of this forum, which is supposed to be about music.